# hi friends, how could i retrieve the contact list to save them

Tags: android, listview, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csBM0.png)

I would like to retrieve the information to save, 
- Listview
- TextFieldForm

Answer (score 0):

First make a data structure to hold the contact data.  Then provide an `onSaved` function to each TextFormField that saves the value to the data structure.